# How to add value to an array on click (Javascript) and remove it if it's already in

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, click

My problem's here:

I need to add value to an array (which is empty), on click on an element in the dom. It'll add the data-id to the array. I need to make a loop to add multiple data-id to this array but I failed when I want to remove it if it's already in.

Any idea ? Here is the code:

```
    $arr = [];
    $('.friends-list').live('click', function(){

    var $str = $(this).attr('data-id'),
        $yourFriends = false;

        $arr.push($str);

        console.log($arr);



    if($ids != ''){
        $('#jsSubmit').removeClass('desactive');
        $yourFriends = true
    }

    if($yourFriends == true){
        $('#jsSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
    }else {
        $('#jsSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
    }

});
```

Comment: Put the $arr = []; outside the click scope (make it global for test). It's reseting every time a new click is triggered.

Comment: Also, the `live()` method has been deprecated and is no longer supported in the latest jQuery builds. You should use the `on()` method, with 3 arguments instead.

Comment: The point is that my elements are not in the dom at the beginning. They're generated after a click... But i'll try this ! Edit: It's working lol... I'm idiot... Now I've to try to remove the value if the data-id is already in the array !

Comment: initialize your array object just above the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this would fill your array with the data-id of every .friends-list

```
$('.friends-list').live('click', function(){
...
    var arr = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < jQuery(this).length; x++){
       var dataIDstr = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
       arr.push(dataIDstr);
    }
...
```

i hope i understood what you were looking for, let me know! :)

Plus it is suggested to use .on() instead of .live()

Best

Comment: It work perfectly, now i'm gonna try to remove the data-id if it's already in. Thx dude !

Comment: what do you mean exactly? if you let me understand your problem i could try to help you.